# how to find a repeated event in time series?

Tags: python, time-series, seasonality, repeated-pattern, date

I need to find the repeated events in time series. if one event always has the similar value, similar description, and happens at similar date, then it is a repeated pattern. Let me make an example here:

Say my time series has date, value and description. A pattern A is a single data point in the time series. A always happens at 1st, 2nd of every month. The value of A is around 100~103. Its description is like 'buy coke', 'buy pepsi 100' etc. Then A is a repeated pattern. There should be different thresholds to define how much the variety could be.

If a event does not match any of these three conditions, then it is not a repeated pattern.

Any ml algorithm can deal with such problem, and what the python library is?